# Issue regarding copying

Tags: files, scp

I have one file which is of 60GB i need to copy it to cloud server from local server

steps i am following
I am splitting file (`nohup split -b 10G filename.gz &`) into chunks which is of 10GB and

Then copying to cloud server once it reaches destination
I am doing
`zcat xa* > file.gz`

at that time we are getting below error

```
gzip: xaa: unexpected end of file
```

what are the steps to be followed to overcome this issue

command i am using to copy
`scp -i .pem filename user@hostname:/path`

Comment: I would checksum the file before and after upload to make sure they were not corrupted in transit. Use something like `sha256sum` on each end and make sure they match. If any don't match, you'll need to re-upload them.

Comment: You shouldn't do `zcat xa*` but `cat xa*`. You have broken a gzipped file into chunks. You can't gunzip them separately and first need to reconstitute the whole file. Also `zcat anything > something.gz` makes no sense at all, as the left hand side _unzips_.

Comment: Also, instead of `scp`, better use `rsync` and do away with the whole splitting complexity. `rsync` will resume partial copies.